# Affiliate codes and self promotion

Tags: discussion

Please do not post answers containing affiliate codes or affiliate links. If your answer is [deleted once](https://monero.stackexchange.com/a/2879/11) please do not post the same answer again and expect different results.

> You should try *deleted promoted software download link* They Have Altcoins Faucet (once a day), including Monero.
>
> Also, you must consider invest in Cloud Mining, I recommend *deleted cloud mining referral link* I receive payment every two days, the customer support is very friendly, and they always have promotions! You Get 3% off on any Genesis hashpower plan, using Promo Code: *deleted referral code*

If you have a relationship with a new Monero software or service described in your answer please make that disclosure. If your answer contains link to software downloads, please state whether or not it is open source and point to the source code when available.

If you are part of the Monero community, please try to use Stack Exchange for more than just promoting your software or service. Ask and answer other questions.

Comment: This is spam. The most effective tool you have against this, as moderators, is to destroy the accounts that are posting these things.

Comment: @ArtOfCode Unfortunately these messages have so far been from 0 day accounts which can easily be created again. How many spam messages do you think we should eliminate before deleting offending accounts? In the case above there were 2. Is that enough?

Comment: @SmartKid If it's a newly-created account that's only got one spam post, just destroy it. No need to wait for another one to pop up - destroying the account slows 'em down even if it *can* be created again. It also sends some signal to the spam blocking system to block the IP.